# What is the proper term for the verb + path portion of a complete route?

Tags: path, url-routing

Regardless of the underlying programming language implementation, I've been unable to find any documentation that names the "left portion" of a complete route.  For example, using javascript, if the complete route is...

```
'GET /user/new': 'UserController.new'
```

...where the right side consists of a controller `User` and an action `new`, what do you call the left hand portion of the route?  I know it consists of a the verb `get` and a path `/user/new`, but is there a proper term for what they are together?  `Request` is too broad.  I don't want to use `route` because it seems clearer to say the entire thing is a route.

Comment: `get` = a request method, `/user/new` = a request-uri, but I don't know of term describing their combination. [Request-Line](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html) seems close.